# ThreadPoolExecutor on java doc

Tags: java, multithreading

at http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html
you can read the description of parameters to constructor.
Specifically in the "Core and maximum pool sizes" paragraph, it's written:

> If there are more than corePoolSize but less than maximumPoolSize threads running, a new thread will be created only if the queue is full.

...

> By setting maximumPoolSize to an essentially unbounded value such as Integer.MAX_VALUE, you allow the pool to accommodate an arbitrary number of concurrent tasks.

Now I can't understand what "only if the queue is full" in the first part stands for...
Will ThreadPoolExecutor wait until queue is full or it will simply create a new worker?

An suppose now that we have more tasks that aren't asynchronous between them: using a ThreadPoolExecutor could cause a deadlock? Supposing that my first 10 tasks are producer and that CorePoolSize is 10, then succeeding consumer tasks will go to queue and won't run until the queue is full? If so this behavior may cause deadlock because first 10 producers could go on wait, suspending all 10 threads of the Core.
When the queue is full?
I'm not sure I understood well the documentation, because Executors.newCachedThreadPool() seems to create a new Worker until maxPoolSize is reached and THEN it sends task to queue.
I'm a little confused.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you construct the ThreadPoolExecutor, you pass in an instance of `BlockingQueue<Runnable>` called `workQueue`, to hold the tasks, and it is this queue that is being referred to.

In fact, the section of the docs called "Queuing" goes into more detail about the phrase you're confused about:

> Any BlockingQueue may be used to transfer and hold submitted tasks. The use of this queue interacts with pool sizing:
>
> - If fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, the Executor always prefers adding a new thread rather than queuing.
> - If corePoolSize or more threads are running, the Executor always prefers queuing a request rather than adding a new thread.
> - If a request cannot be queued, a new thread is created unless this would exceed maximumPoolSize, in which case, the task will be rejected.

---

As for your second part, about inter-task dependencies - in this case I don't think it's a good idea to put them into an ExecutorService *at all*.  The ExecutorService is good for running a self-contained bit of code at some point in the future, but by design it's not meant to be strongly deterministic about when this happens, other than "at some convenient point in the (hopefully near) future, after tasks that were previously queued have started."

Combine this lack of precision of timing, with the hard ordering requirements that concurrent operation imposes, and you can see that having a producer and a consumer that need to talk to each other, put into a general purpose ExecutorService, is a recipe for very annoying and confusing bugs.

*Yes*, I'm sure you could get it to work with sufficient tweaking of parameters.  However, it wouldn't be clear why it worked, it wouldn't be clear what the dependencies were, and *when* (not if) it broke, it would be very hard to diagnose.  (Harder than normal concurrency problems, I suspect).  The bottom line is that an ExecutorService isn't designed to run Runnables with hard timing restrictions, so this could even be broken by a new release of Java, because it doesn't *have* to work like this.

I think you're asking the wrong question, by looking at the details when perhaps your concepts are a little shaky.  Perhaps if you explained what you wanted to achieve there would be a better way to go about it.

Comment: Thank you, I'm just studying java and the more I go deeply inside the japi, the more I see it's unbelievably enormous.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify your first quote - if the executor already has `corePoolSize` threads running, and all of those threads are busy when a new task is submitted, it will *not* create any more threads, but will enqueue the task until one of the threads becomes free. It will only create a new thread (up to the `maxPoolSize` limit) when the queue becomes full. If the queue is huge (i.e. bounded only by memory constraints) then no more than `corePoolSize` threads will ever be created.

`Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` will create an executor with a zero-sized queue, so the queue is *always* full. This means that it will create a new thread (or re-use an idle one) as soon as you submit the task. As such, it's not a good demonstration of what the core/max/queue parameters are for.